# In ggplot2, what is the difference between aesthetic mappings included in the ggplot function and first geom function?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When looking at examples of making basic plots using `ggplot2`, I have noticed that some examples provide the aesthetic mappings for their x and y axes in the original `ggplot()` function. On the other hand, other examples only provide the `data` in the `ggplot()` call, and provide the aesthetic mappings for x and y in whatever `geom_` argument they use. Both examples create the same plots. Is there a functional difference that matters? Is this a matter of preference, or are there appropriate times for each?

```r
data(mpg)
ggplot(mpg, aes(x=displ, y=hwy))+
  geom_point()
ggplot(mpg)+
  geom_point(aes(x=displ, y=hwy))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ggplot` uses a hierachical system of layers to provide detailled control over the plots.

Consider the following two cases:

Here we specify the element `color` in the geom. Therefore it is only going to be used by `geom_point()` but not by `geom_line()` (the lines are black)

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=cyl)) +
  geom_line()
```

In the second example the element `color` is specified in the `ggplot()` call. It is going to be used by **all** subsequent layers (`geom_point()` and `geom_line()` use it)

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, hp, color=cyl)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```